# How to build JPA predicate for JSONB column?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a JSONB column in Postgres and I want to filter data based on key value pairs stored inside JSON.
I am currently using Spring Data JPA and I want to use Predicates to dynamically fire SQL queries.

One option I found is Native Query where the syntax could be as follows:

```
SELECT car0_.model_name, car0_.year_of_manufacture, car0_.properties 
FROM public.car AS car0_ 
WHERE car0_.year_of_manufacture < 2010 
AND car0_.properties ->> 'country_of_manufacture'='US';
```

But I do not wish to use Native Queries since it defeat the purpose of using ORM.

Moreover I have to build query dynamically instead having static queries so that user can search based on any key value pair within the JSON.

Comment: That might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is applicable to Hibernate 5.0 until 6.0.

First you need to open-up psql and find out what function does the operator `->>` correspond to using `\doS+ ->>`. In this case `jsonb_object_field_text` making your desired condition `jsonb_object_field_text(car0_.properties, 'country_of_manufacture') = 'US'`.

Now you need to register that function in Hibernate to be able to use it in JPQL. To do so you have to implement a `MetadataBuilderInitializer` in let's say your package is `com.mysite.util`.

```
package com.mysite.util;

import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;

public class SQLFunctionContributor implements MetadataBuilderInitializer {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder, StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("jsonb_object_field_text", new StandardSQLFunction("jsonb_object_field_text", StringType.INSTANCE));
    }

}
```

The final step is to create a text file within your resource folder with the following path:

```
META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer
```

The file has to contain the qualified class name of your new class:

```
com.mysite.util.SQLFunctionContributor
```

Now you can use the function in JPQL like so:

```
SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.yearOfManufacture < :year AND FUNCTION('jsonb_object_field_text', c.properties, 'country_of_manufacture') = :cc
```

Comment: The drawback of using the function instead of the operator is, that the function won't use an index where the operator would

Comment: If that is true, then perhaps the PostgreSQL team should consider registering its index detection to the underlying functions, instead of the operators. However it's this or native queries. Most problems don't have a perfect solution.

Comment: You could also just contribute a SQLFunction that renders the operator...